# very basic avoid the monster find the door game, can't get the walls to stop the player going through them

Tags: python

A very basic game of the player who is an 'x' has to avoid the monster and get through the door (both are invisible). My function "which_way" is not keeping the player "x" within the outside walls of my grid, the player can disappear through them if you keep typing "LEFT" for example. Also the .upper() is not working on the same function. Thanks.

```
import random



game = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0),
        (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1),
        (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2),
        (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3),
        (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4)]



def get_playerdoormonster():
    return random.sample(game, 3)


def print_board(player):
    print("_" * 11)
    for spot in game:
        x, y = spot
        if x < 5:
            if spot == player:
                print("|X", end="")
            else:
                print("|_", end="")
        else:
            print("|")
            if spot == player:
                print("X")
            else:
                print("|")

def what_is_move(x, y): 
    move = ["RIGHT", "LEFT", "UP", "DOWN"]
    if x > 4:
        move.remove("RIGHT")
    if x < 1:
        move.remove("LEFT")
    if y > 3:
        move.remove("DOWN")
    if y < 1:
        move.remove("UP")
    return move


def which_way(x, y, move):  
    while True: 
        move_decision = input("Would you like to move {} :".format(", ".join(move)))
        move_decision = move_decision.upper()
        if move_decision in move: 
            if move_decision == "UP":
                y -= 1
                break
            elif move_decision == "DOWN":
                y += 1
                break
            elif move_decision == "RIGHT":
                x += 1
                break
            elif move_decision == "LEFT":
                x -= 1
                break
            else:
                continue
        else:
            print("Ouch! Walls hurt!")
    return x, y


def monster_or_door(player, door, monster):
    if player == monster:
        print("GAMES OVER")
        return True

    elif player == door:
        print("YOU WIN! YOU ESCAPED!")
        return True
    else:
        return False


def game_time():
    player, door, monster = get_playerdoormonster()

    while True:

        print_board(player)
        x, y = player


        move = what_is_move(x, y)

        player = which_way(x, y, move)


        is_it_over = monster_or_door(player, door, monster)

        if is_it_over:
            play_again = input("Play again? Y/n").upper()
            play_again = play_again.upper()
            if play_again != "N":
                game_time()
            else:
                break





game_time()
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get the "OUCH" message on all four sides.  Also, when I type a direction in lower case, I get the move just as if I'd typed it in upper-case.  Can you please provide a driver program to demonstrate the problems?

Comment: Oh really? Thanks for checking, I'm using a windows laptop that's probably 5 years old and running it in the windows command prompt. I should look into something else then as the command prompt apparently does not work well.

Comment: It says the python was updated just a month ago, sooo not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: Neither am I, since you haven't actually demonstrated the problem.